# Determine when $f_{a}(x)$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For some $a\in \Bbb{R}$ define a function $f_{a}(x) =
\begin{cases}
{x^{a}\cos{1\over x}},  & \text{if $x$ $\ne$ 0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

What should $a$ be in order for $f_{a}(x)$ to be bounded?

I am a bit confused... $cos{1\over x}$ is bounded by $-1,1$ so every real $a$ should give a bound, is it not so??

Comment: Of course, I was wrong.

Comment: Hint: When will the function $x^a$ be bounded?

Comment: That's a good hint. Thanks.

Comment: Only when $a\le 0$?

Comment: If $a<0$, $x^a$ becomes unbounded around $0$.

Comment: But it $f(0)=0$...

Comment: If $a>0$ I can't seem to understand how it can be bounded :<

Comment: If $a>0$, then $x^a \to + \infty$ when $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: Taking "0" into account, no $a$ gives a bound. $a\le 0$ gives a bound when $x\ne 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel No, if $a \lt 0$ then you get $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^{a}}$ which, as John stated, becomes unbounded as $x \rightarrow 0$.. What about $a = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If $\;a>0\;$ , then

$$f_a(x)=x^a\cos\frac1x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;\cos\frac1x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1$$

2) If $\;a<0\;$ , then

$$f_a\left(\frac1{2n\pi}\right)=\frac1{(2n\pi)^a}\overbrace{\cos2n\pi}^{=1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Well, what $\;a\;$ then works **for sure** ?

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.

Comment: That was silly of me not to consider the case when $x<0$. I am anticipating an exam.